# Spark Streaming with MongoDB backend

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, streaming

I have a requirement to read csv files that will be pumped from the telemetry equipment into a location on cloud and store the relevant data into Mongodb store. I am using Spark Streaming to read new files (they arrive every minute, sometimes even more frequent) and using MomgoDB-Spark connector.The problem is that the data is not being loaded into MomgoDB. I have added Dataframe's show() steps in my code and they are being displayed at the console correctly, which means Streaming application is reading and processing the files as expected. But the final step of saving to MongoDB is not happening. My code looks as follows

```
reqdata.foreachRDD { edata =>
    import sqlContext.implicits._
    val loaddata = edata.map(w => EnergyData(w(0).toString,w(1).toString,w(2).toString)).toDF()
    loaddata.show()
    loaddata.printSchema(); 
    MongoSpark.save(loaddata.write.option("uri","mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/storedata.energydata").mode("overwrite"))
}

ssc.start()
```

The `loaddata.show()` function is displaying the data just fine.

I have checked the Mongodb logs and found few strange lines like

> "2016-09-07T08:12:30.109-0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55694 #212 (3 connections now open)
>   2016-09-07T08:12:30.111-0700 I COMMAND  [conn212] CMD: drop storedata.energydata"

Now, I don't understand why Mongo would drop the collection at all.
Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: _I don't understand why Mongo would drop the collection at all_ - `.mode("overwrite")`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself by changing the saving mode to `append`:

```
MongoSpark.save(loaddata.write.option("uri","mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/storedata.energydata").mode("append"))
```